# How to adjust databases of Chinese inputing method in Ubuntu?

Tags: input-language, input-method, chinese, fcitx

It might be a problem faced by Chinese users.
A couple of articles in Chinese Ubuntu online community suggest to download a larger database and replace the primitive database in usr/share/fcitx/pinyin to enlarge the database to improve efficiency and accuracy while inputing Chinese.
The database I have downloaded from here.
https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/hslinuxextra/fcitx.7z
I extracted the files and moved them to /usr/share/fcitx/pinyin with a command.
sudo mv pybase.mb pyphrase.mb /usr/share/fcitx/pinyin
after that, I find the system collapsed.
What’s wrong with this activity?
And any suggestion for adjusting these databases?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how the Fcitx internals work. But please note that there are alternatives to _fcitx-pinyin_ in the Ubuntu archive. You may want to install the _fcitx-sunpinyin_ or _fcitx-libpinyin_ package and try one of those input methods instead.

Comment: I have tried fcitx-sunpinyin and it is working well. Also, the compatibility of fcitx-sunpinyin seems better. The phase database of fcitx-sunpinyin is kept in home/.sunpinyin as a userdict file. This file is very small and it seems fcitx-sunpinyin is working on this userdict file, as well as the the primitive database of fcitx-pinyin. This userdict file can be replaced by a larger database to improve efficiency and accuracy while inputing. The only problem is, fcitx-sunpin is working slower with a larger database.

Comment: I see. Myself I don't speak any language which requires input methods, so I'm not able to evaluate how user friendly they are. Anyway, great that the change proved to be an improvement.

Comment: Thanks. It is a great challenge to introduce Chinese inputing on typewriter after it is invented. On computer there is a great progress to support Chinese inputing with a phase database. However, more should be done to improve Chinese inputing.

Comment: You may want to get in touch with the [Ubuntu Kylin](https://launchpad.net/ubuntukylin) project. Unlike standard Ubuntu, which has switched back to Ibus in 17.10, Ubuntu Kylin, with many users who type Simplified Chinese, keeps using Fcitx, and can be assumed to continuously look for the best input method tools.